# Transactions in C#

Tags: c#, methods, transactions

In addition to this question: [Preorder tree traversal copy folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577080/preorder-tree-traversal-copy-folder)
I was wondering if it is possible to create a transaction that contains different calls to the database.

ex:

```
public bool CopyNode(int nodeId, int parentNode)
    { 
        // Begin transaction.
        try
        {
            Method1(nodeId);
            Method2(nodeId, parentNode);
            Method3(nodeId);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        { 
            //rollback all the methods
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this is possible. We are using subsonic to do the database calls.
This is really important, not only for the tree traversal problem but also for some other stuff we do.

The main idea is that we can't let our dabase get corrupted with uncomplete data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible, you can find a example [here](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/transactions.html)

Or perhaps a transaction scope...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx

Comment: Oh sorry, then, perhaps a transaction scope would help, I never worked with this, but here is the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx

Answer (score 1):

BeginTransaction is called off a ADO.NET collection object.
The Command object needs this transaction (SqlTransaction object) assigned to it.
Commit and Rollback are only called in the outer method.

Check out this code.  It works by re-using the SqlConnection and SqlTransaction objects.  This is a classic Master>Details type of set up.  The master type is `ColumnHeaderSet` which contains a property of

> `List<ColumnHeader>`

, which is the details (collection).

Hope this helps.
-JM

```
public static int SaveColumnHeaderSet(ColumnHeaderSet set)
      //save a ColumnHeaderSet
      {       
         string sp = ColumnSP.usp_ColumnSet_C.ToString();    //name of sp we're using
         SqlCommand cmd = null;
         SqlTransaction trans = null;
         SqlConnection conn = null;

         try
         {
            conn = SavedRptDAL.GetSavedRptConn();  //get conn for the app's connString
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sp, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Transaction = trans;   // Includes this cmd as part of the trans

            //parameters
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColSetName", set.ColSetName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DefaultSet", 0);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Author", set.Author.UserID);   
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAnonymous", set.IsAnonymous);         
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientNum", set.Author.ClientNum);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShareLevel", set.ShareLevel);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Type", set.Type);

            //add output parameter - to return new record identity
            SqlParameter prm = new SqlParameter();
            prm.ParameterName = "@ID_ColSet";
            prm.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int i = Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ID_ColSet"].Value.ToString());
            if (i == 0) throw new Exception("Failed to save ColumnHeaderSet");
            set.ColSetID = i; //update the object

            //save the ColumnHeaderList (SetDetail)
            if (ColumnHeader_Data.SaveColumnHeaderList(set, conn, trans)==false) throw new Exception("Failed to save ColumnHeaderList");
            trans.Commit();

            // return ID for new ColHdrSet
            return i;
         }
         catch (Exception e){
            trans.Rollback();
            throw e;
         }
         finally{
            conn.Close();
         }
      }

 public static bool SaveColumnHeaderList(ColumnHeaderSet set, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trans)
      //save a (custom)ColHeaderList for a Named ColumnHeaderSet
      {
         // we're going to accept a SqlTransaction to maintain transactional integrity
         string sp = ColumnSP.usp_ColumnList_C.ToString();    //name of sp we're using 
         SqlCommand cmd = null;
         try
         {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sp, conn);     // re-using the same conection object
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Transaction = trans;            // includes the cmd in the transaction

            //build params collection (input)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_ColSet", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_ColHeader", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Selected", SqlDbType.Bit);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Position", SqlDbType.Int);

            //add output parameter - to return new record identity
            //FYI - @return_value = @ID_SavedRpt
            SqlParameter prm = new SqlParameter();
            prm.ParameterName = "@ID";
            prm.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            //Loop
            foreach (ColumnHeader item in set.ColHeaderList)
            {
               //set param values
               cmd.Parameters["@ID_ColSet"].Value = set.ColSetID; 
               cmd.Parameters["@ID_ColHeader"].Value = item.ColHeaderID; 
               cmd.Parameters["@Selected"].Value = item.Selected;
               cmd.Parameters["@Position"].Value = item.Position;

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               int i = Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value.ToString());
               if (i == 0) throw new Exception("Failed to save ColumnHeaderSet");
            } 
            return true;
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            throw e;            
         }

      }
```